# Dataflow export to Bigquery: insertAll error, invalid table reference

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to create and export a stream of synthetic data using Dataflow, Pub/Sub, and BigQuery. I followed the [synthetic data generation instructions](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/dataflow-flex-template-streaming-data-generator) using the following schema:

```
{
    "id": "{{uuid()}}",
    "test_value": {{integer(1,50)}}
}
```

The schema is in a file `gs://my-folder/my-schema.json`. The stream seems to be running correctly - I can export from the corresponding Pub/Sub topic to a GCS bucket using the "Export to Cloud Storage" template. When I try to use the "Export to BigQuery" template, I keep getting this error:

```
Request failed with code 400, performed 0 retries due to IOExceptions, performed 0 retries due to unsuccessful status codes, HTTP framework says request can be retried, (caller responsible for retrying): https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/<my-project>/datasets/<my-dataset>/tables/<my-table>/insertAll.
```

Before starting the export job, I created an empty table `<my-project>:<my-dataset>.<my-table>` with fields that match the JSON schema above:

```
id          STRING  NULLABLE    
test_value  INTEGER NULLABLE
```

I have `outputTableSpec` set to `<my-project>:<my-dataset>.<my-table>`.

Comment: You use the legacy BQ table description. Did you try with standard format? project.dataset.table

Comment: If I try that, the UI shows an error `Value must be of the form: ".+:.+\..+"` and doesn't allow me to run the job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the BQ table name is given in the form `project:dataset.table`, then there cannot be any hyphens in the `table` string. I was using `my-project.test.stream-data-102720` when I got the code 400 error. Creating a new table `my-project.test.stream_data_102720` and re-running the job with the new name fixed the problem.

Comment: Geez this was NOT obvious at all with the python SDK. thanks